# How to show docker container process on Mac Os

Tags: macos, process

Docker processes running in a container should be visible on the host as well.

When I run `docker top` on one of my container I see the pid of the process which is supposed to run on the host, but I can't find it running `ps -ef` command. Is it hidden? how can I see it listing the process?

On a RHEL system, I can see that straight away

I'm using Catalina 10.15.3

Comment: macOS isn't Linux and doesn't run Linux binaries. How could a Linux process running inside a Linux based Docker image / container show up in macOS's process table? There's a thicker VM-like layer running when you run Docker on macOS.

Comment: that makes sense, I thought that was probably hidden by another process. But I was wondering if there was a way to see that process tree (as the docker top is actually returning a pid, which I guess is a subprocess)

Answer (score 1):

I'm a complete Docker noobie, but a Docker course on Udemy by Bret Fisher mentions this problem on macOS and points to a solution by [Justin Cormack](https://github.com/justincormack/nsenter1). I don't actually understand the details of Justin's solution, but I managed to achieve what the OP is asking for: to see the processes running inside the docker containers running on the host machine, which is a virtual machine that Docker uses on macOS. Here's how:

Step 1) show the processes running in a specific container, e.g. one called 'database':

```
docker container top database
```

Result:
[image]

Step 2) enter the 'virtual machine' on a Mac, where all the docker containers are running, by using the command in relation to Justin Cormack's repo :

```
docker run -it --rm --privileged --pid=host justincormack/nsenter1
```

Result:

[image]

Notice the changed prompt. Now you're inside the VM. You can further investigate the VM e.g. with `ls -la`

Step 3) Use the plain `top` command, (not e.g. `docker container top`, there's no `docker` command available on the VM)

Result:

[image]

Notice that along with other processes on the VM the list also shows the process with PID 3532, which is the mysql process from the container (see step 1).

4) to exit the processes type `ctrl+C`, and to exit the VM type `exit`

And you're back home on your real macOS.

Hope this is helpful to other noobies like myself. :)